# MySQL sort by subquery result. Null last, > 0 as 1

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, sql-null

I have a query that I would like to sort in a specific way. First if "antall" is > 0, I want it to be sorted as 1 so that every row that has antall > 0 will be internally sorted by a.tittel. And if antall IS NULL I want it to be last.

```
SELECT a.tittel,
(SELECT SUM(antall) FROM butikk_lager WHERE butikkdata_nr=ai.valueNumber 
    AND lokasjon NOT LIKE 'Uts%' AND lokasjon NOT LIKE 'Rekl%' 
    AND ( varenr='TK180126' OR variant_artid LIKE '%TK180126%' ) LIMIT 0,1 ) AS antall
FROM artikler AS a 
JOIN kategorier AS k ON a.kategori_id=k.id 
JOIN artikler_innhold AS ai ON a.id=ai.artId AND ai.feltId=22
WHERE k.type=24 ORDER BY ?, a.tittel
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
order by (antal > 0) desc, a.title
```

`(antal > 0)` yields `1` if `antal` is greater than `0`, `0` if it is `0` or less, and `null` if it is `null`. You can put a descending sort on that: MySQL puts `null`s last when sorting in that direction.

Comment: It won't put NULL last though?

Comment: @johnohod: yes it does, as explained in the answer. Give the query a try.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't put NULL last in my database

Comment: @johnohod: that's suprising. Are you able to set up a [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There are a few complex tables involved. But I tried to replace "antall" with the actual subquery and then your solutions works. So I guess I just can't use "antall" to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want `antal` to be last when it is `NULL`, then:

```
order by (antal is not null) desc, title desc
```

However, I think GMB's solution with the descending sort should also work.